# I can't update rows after I delete a invalid row from a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

When I remove an item from an `ObservableCollection` that has invalid data in it the `datagrid` won't clear the fact that it has errors so once I delete it it acts like the `DataGrid` still has errors and won't allow me to edit/add and edit data.

I'm using **MVVM** so I can't just do `datagrid.refresh` :\

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the item getting deleted from the ViewModel and your not seeing the change in the DataGrid? Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged? Try adding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" to the source binding for the items of the DataGrid.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when an exception occurs the binding is broken.

Comment: its getting delete from the viewmodel and it updates in the datagrid, but the datagrid does not know that there is no longer any invalid rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this using Phil's answer:

```
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this[index] = new EngineStatusUserFilter();
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        Refresh();

    }

    public void Refresh() {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)); }
```

I set the old object to a new one before removing it so it will be valid.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work, but you can try telling the data grid the entire collection has changed:

Two options:

1) Raise a property change notification for the collection property.

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items { ... }
}
```

2) Derive from ObservableCollection so that you can raise a NotifyCollectionChanged event

```
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<DataItem>
{
    public void Refresh()
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of works, it will allow me to edit new rows but not rows that were created before the deletion of the invalid row.

Answer (score 0):

After removing item (that have validation error) from ObservableCollection, recreate ObservableCollection and raise OnPropertyChanged.

This refresh DataGrid, rows you are created before delete remains and are editable because validation error of removed item/row is gone.

Like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
...
private void DeleteRowCommand_Method()
{
    Persons.Remove(SelectedPerson);
    Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(Persons);
    OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
}
...
```

Comment: This seems to resolve the issue, but unlike the solutions above that broadcast a "Reset," this has a side-effect of undoing any sorting that was applied to the grid columns.